# how to use time function to get hourly data

Tags: sql

I am trying to get hourly data on a table which was working fine on mysql but not on sql. how to use this in sql server managmenmt studio, i receive 'time' is not a recognized function name.and curdate() is not recognise function.

```
  select  [pa_number], [pa_surname]
      ,[pa_forename],
        sum(time(datetime) >= '07:00:00' and time(datetime) < '08:00:00') as '7.00-8.00 AM',  
       sum(time(datetime) >= '08:00:00' and time(datetime) < '09:00:00') as '8.00-9.00 AM',  
       sum(time(datetime) >= '09:00:00' and time(datetime) < '10:00:00') as '9.00-10.00 AM ',  
       sum(time(datetime) >= '10:00:00' and time(datetime) < '11:00:00') as '10.00-11.00 AM',   
       sum(time(datetime) >= '11:00:00' and time(datetime) < '12:00:00') as '11.00-12.00 AM',   
   sum(time(datetime) >= '12:00:00' and time(datetime) < '13:00:00') as '12.00-1.00 PM',   
   sum(time(datetime) >= '13:00:00' and time(datetime) < '14:00:00') as '1.00-2.00 PM',   
   sum(time(datetime) >= '14:00:00' and time(datetime) < '15:00:00') as '2.00-3.00 PM',  
   sum(time(datetime) >= '15:00:00' and time(datetime) < '16:00:00') as '3.00-4.00 PM',   
   sum(time(datetime) >= '16:00:00' and time(datetime) < '17:00:00') as '4.00-5.00 PM',  
   sum(time(datetime) >= '17:00:00' and time(datetime) < '18:00:00') as '5.00-6.00 PM',  
   sum(time(datetime) >= '18:00:00' and time(datetime) < '19:00:00') as '6.00-7.00 PM'   



 from [ICPS].[dbo].[parking_attendants] t  
   inner join tickets a  
   on t.[pa_number] = a.[t_pa_number]  

  where cast(t.DATETIME AS DATE) = CURDATE()  
  group by pa_surname
```

Comment: Which RDMS is this related to ?

Comment: sql server managmenmt studio

Comment: looks like Postgres - if it was SQL Server I'd group by DatePart(hour, datetime) - not sure if there is the same function in Postgres ?

Comment: 'CURDATE' is not a recognized built-in function name in SQL Server ? I seem to remember it from my Postgres days though ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Server, the MySQL `time()` function does not have an exact equivalent. That said, in your example you could use SQL Server's `DatePart()` function.

However in SQL Server, the MySQL `CURDATE()` function does have an equivalent: `GetDate()` (for local datetime data), `GetUtcDate()` (for UTC [aka. GMT] datetime data), or `SysDateTimeOffset()` (for datetimeoffset [datetime with timezone] data).

Your SQL statement could be re-written as:

```
SELECT
    [pa_number],
    [pa_surname],
    [pa_forename],
    Sum(CASE WHEN DatePart(hour, [datetime]) >=  7 AND DatePart(hour, [datetime]) <  8 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '7.00-8.00 AM',
    Sum(CASE WHEN DatePart(hour, [datetime]) >=  8 AND DatePart(hour, [datetime]) <  9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '8.00-9.00 AM',
    Sum(CASE WHEN DatePart(hour, [datetime]) >=  9 AND DatePart(hour, [datetime]) < 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '9.00-10.00 AM',
    Sum(CASE WHEN DatePart(hour, [datetime]) >= 10 AND DatePart(hour, [datetime]) < 11 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '10.00-11.00 AM',
    Sum(CASE WHEN DatePart(hour, [datetime]) >= 11 AND DatePart(hour, [datetime]) < 12 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '11.00-12.00 PM',
    Sum(CASE WHEN DatePart(hour, [datetime]) >= 12 AND DatePart(hour, [datetime]) < 13 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '12.00-1.00 PM',
    Sum(CASE WHEN DatePart(hour, [datetime]) >= 13 AND DatePart(hour, [datetime]) < 14 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '1.00-2.00 PM',
    Sum(CASE WHEN DatePart(hour, [datetime]) >= 14 AND DatePart(hour, [datetime]) < 15 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '2.00-3.00 PM',
    Sum(CASE WHEN DatePart(hour, [datetime]) >= 15 AND DatePart(hour, [datetime]) < 16 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '3.00-4.00 PM',
    Sum(CASE WHEN DatePart(hour, [datetime]) >= 16 AND DatePart(hour, [datetime]) < 17 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '4.00-5.00 PM',
    Sum(CASE WHEN DatePart(hour, [datetime]) >= 17 AND DatePart(hour, [datetime]) < 18 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '5.00-6.00 PM',
    Sum(CASE WHEN DatePart(hour, [datetime]) >= 18 AND DatePart(hour, [datetime]) < 19 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '6.00-7.00 PM'
FROM
    [ICPS].[dbo].[parking_attendants] AS t
    INNER JOIN [tickets] AS a
        ON ( a.[t_pa_number] = t.[pa_number] )
WHERE
    /* Cast(t.[datetime] AS date) = Cast(GetDate() AS date) --Commented out during edit */
    DateAdd(day, DateDiff(day, 0, Cast(t.[datetime] AS datetime)), 0) = DateAdd(day, DateDiff(day, 0, GetDate()), 0)
GROUP BY
    [pa_number],
    [pa_surname],
    [pa_forename]
```

Beware of SQL Server's `BETWEEN` operator in your case, since it is inclusive to the data elements tested:

> BETWEEN returns **TRUE** if the value of *test_expression* is greater than or equal to the value of *begin_expression* and less than or equal to the value of *end_expression*.

**EDIT:** Based on your comment, you are using either SQL Server 2000 or 2005, both of which did not yet have the *date* datatype. The SQL statement (above) has been modified to use the more universal *datetime* datatype. The `DateAdd(day, DateDiff(day, 0, {datetime}), 0)` portion of the statement is used to cleanse, or zero-out, the time portion (that is, ##:##:## => 00:00:00) of a datetime. This allows two datetimes to be compared (sans time) as pseudo-date datatypes.

Comment: Type date is not a defined system type. i get this error

Comment: The answer has been modified to be SQL Server 2000+ compatible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SUM(DATEPART(HOUR, t.datetime) BETWEEN 7 AND 8)` etc. for the first part, and `CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)` for the second

MS reference for [DATEPART](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx), [BETWEEN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187922.aspx), [GETDATE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx)